# How to configure test and production databases and code using JOOQ

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I am new to JOOQ and love learning and using it.

I am at the point where I want to do some testing, but instead of testing
on the 'real' database I want to use a 'copy' of that database.

When using jdbc all it really took was changing the database name in the 
create statement and using that name when connecting to the database.

I quickly discovered that anything I tried to write to my test database
was ending up in the production database

In the JOOQ documentation it looked like I could solve the problem with some mapping.

I added a Settings class and got the DSLContext using the settings, as shown below

My base database name is 'kpi'.

```
Connection conn = JooqUtil.getConnection("user", "pw", kpitest, hostip, sb);
Settings settings = new Settings()
        .withRenderMapping(new RenderMapping()
                .withSchemata(
                        new MappedSchema().withInput(kpi)
                                .withOutput(kpitest)));
// Add the settings to the DSLContext
if (sb.length() == 0) {
    dsl = DSL.using(conn, SQLDialect.MYSQL, settings);
}
```

The above resulted in seeing the testName database being used,
BUT access to the tables and fields was using the productionName.

Going back to the documentation it looks like there is a way to map the tables
also but it  looks like a lot of work.

Further reading, I found some settings in the configuration file using schemata

My current JOOQ configuration xml file contains

```
<inputSchema>kpi</inputSchema>
```

It looks like I should change it to something like

```
<inputSchema></inputSchema>  << maybe drop altogether
<schemata>
    <schema>
        <inputSchema>kpi</inputSchema>
        <outputSchema>kpi</outputSchema>
    </schema>
    <schema>
        <inputSchema>kpi</inputSchema>
        <outputSchema>kpitest</outputSchema>
    </schema>
</schemata>
```

In reading the manual I was not sure if DEV and PRODUCTION names had literal significance or not.

What would help is a (real world) example where there was a production and test database,
or one develpment database per developer, and how the tables and fields were accessed
if there was a change in syntax.  A change in syntax would be difficult for doing unit type testing though.

Thanks for any quidance and links to examples

Comment: *"NOTE: this has been edited from being a Question to providing an Answer, JM"*: Note that you can answer your own questions on Stack Overflow. It will be easier for future visitors to follow your line of thoughts, this way

Comment: If you have an answer, please post it as such. Please do not edit an answer into the question.